# How to setup MSVC build tools for Rust?

Tags: windows, rust, build-tools

I installed `rustup` in January 2017 without any problems. Recently I tried to do the same and have a huge problem. The [documentation](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/install.html) states that I need to go and install the [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017). This is kind of vague, especially because I've never used any Microsoft product for development.

When I do start the installation, a tons of options appear and total download size goes in gigabytes. After I've installed what I guess would be the right choice it's not visible on path anyway (`cargo build` gives missing linker error, after I fixed that some missing libs show up.) I am using Powershell but on old CMD it behaves the same. Later on I found out there is a link to CMD in Menu Start that will open a CMD shell with correct path, but I'd rather use my ConEmu for that. I do know I could set up PATH manually etc. but this is not right way to do it (or it shouldn't be.) I don't want to be burdened with remembering to fix it later on after installation point changes, etc.

So the question, finally, is.

1. What is the set of minimum necessary components to check in Build Tools VS 2017 installer to be able to develop in Rust.
2. How to set up PATH - automatically, if possible, in order to avoid later manual maintenance.
3. How to set up above tools globally so I can develop and run my apps using IntelliJ or VSCode.

Comment: It is preferred to post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question as well as others hunting for one of your questions.

Comment: This sounds like you should file an issue with rustup to improve their documentation, or [add on to this existing one](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs/issues/1363)

Comment: @Shepmaster I have to admit I couldn't find that link. I really tried, maybe my query wasn't specific enough. Well, I still think question here make sense and all 3 problems listed are closely related. But also I do understand that it's important to keep the questions in bay with the rules and clarity. I'll leave decision to moderators. If you decide to close the question - go ahead.